# Qualtrics Javascript keyboard presses

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics

I've been given some javascript code for recording keyboard presses in Qualtrics. Seems to work fine when I preview the survey, but as soon as I use the distribute survey link, it does not work at all.

I'm using this code for before the event I want to record 'x' keyboard presses for:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function (e) {
        
        switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 88: // 'x' was pressed
                        var totalpresses = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("xhits");
        if (totalpresses == "NaN"){totalpresses=1;}
        totalpresses = parseInt(totalpresses);
                        totalpresses = totalpresses + 1;
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("xhits",totalpresses);
        }
});
});
```

and i'm using this code for following the event:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{ 
        
        var totalpresses = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("xhits");
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("finalxhits", totalpresses);
```

which gives me 'xhits' for the section I need it for, but only when I preview the survey.

I am using embedded data in the survey flow to create 'xhits' and 'finalxhits', yet finalxhits doesn't seem to show a value either (not that this is the problem).

I am very new to javascript so would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing your issue (I haven't tried to recreate it), but try this:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var totalpresses = parseInt("${e://Field/xhits}");
if (isNaN(totalpresses)) totalpresses = 0;
 
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function (e) {
        
        switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 88: // 'x' was pressed
                        totalpresses = totalpresses + 1;
                        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("xhits",totalpresses);
        }
});
});
```

Is that second piece of code attached to a subsequent question? I'm not sure what purpose it serves, but you can just do that assignment in the survey flow:

```
finalxhits = ${e://Field/xhits}
```